# Trying to click on Metamask Login Button and Nothing Happens - Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, metamask

I want to create a scraping program on the PvU site https://marketplace.plantvsundead.com/#/login

I've managed to open Chrome with the Metamask extension and to log in to metamask.

Now I need to login on to the PvU platform, but I can't click on the "Log in with MetaMask" button.

I've tried to click with:

1 -

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.metamask.tw-flex.tw-items-center.tw-p-3.tw-cursor-pointer").click()
```

2 -

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__layout"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/img')
```

3 -

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.metamask.tw-flex.tw-items-center.tw-p-3.tw-cursor-pointer")))
ac.move_to_element(element).click(element).perform()
```

No errors, but nothing happens.

Does anyone know what to do?

My code:

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import sys
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
import asyncio
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time
 
def run_chrome():
    
    #criando uma instância do chrome com o profile escolhido    
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Python")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    ac = ActionChains(driver)
    
    #abrindo o metamask e logando
    driver.get('chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/home.html')
    delay = 3 # seconds
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="password"]')))
        print ("Page is ready!")
    except TimeoutException:
        print ("Loading took too much time!")
    s_pass = "PASSWORD"
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="password"]').send_keys(s_pass)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app-content"]/div/div[4]/div/div/button/span').click()
    
    #abrindo uma nova guia com o metamaks
    EXTENSION_ID = 'nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn'
    driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
    driver.get('chrome-extension://{}/popup.html'.format(EXTENSION_ID))
    
    
    
    #abrindo o PvU
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
    driver.get('https://marketplace.plantvsundead.com/#/login')
    
    #I CAN'T PASS THIS 

    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__layout"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/img')))
        print ("Page is ready!")
    except TimeoutException:
        print ("Loading took too much time!")
    try:
        content = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.metamask.tw-flex.tw-items-center.tw-p-3.tw-cursor-pointer")
        print ("Page is ready!")
    except TimeoutException:
        print ("Loading took too much time!")
    content.click()
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.metamask.tw-flex.tw-items-center.tw-p-3.tw-cursor-pointer")))
    ac.move_to_element(element).click(element).perform()
    
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
    time.sleep(2)
    
run_chrome()
```

THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, this will work for you:

```
ele=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='__layout']//p[starts-with(normalize-space(),'Log in with MetaMask')]")
ele.click()
```

Comment: Nothing. When I click with mouse, it opens a new window with the notification to "sign", and I cant load a page chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/notification.html with the content. But with the code, nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

Tried this locally and the click worked for me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://marketplace.plantvsundead.com/#/login")

item = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "metamask tw-flex tw-items-center tw-p-3")]')))
time.sleep(0.15)
item.click()
```

But I got a popup saying 'Please install metamask'. Have a look here to solve that issue.
[https://dev.to/ltmenezes/automated-dapps-scraping-with-selenium-and-metamask-2ae9](https://dev.to/ltmenezes/automated-dapps-scrapping-with-selenium-and-metamask-2ae9)

Comment: Nothing yet. I have followed the link to get my metamask imported. But i've used a different approach (I created a chrome profile with the extension imported and opened this profile with the selenium).  It seems that the button isn't clicked. When I click with mouse (debug mode) a notification pops in the extension. Another info: when I click with the mouse (debug) chrome opens another window with the notification

Comment: The click still doesnt work? Did you try copy and pasting exactly what i had into a seperate py file? I also tried enthusiasticCoder's xpath and it clicked fine for me

Comment: I actually also copy and pasted what you had and the click happened, so im not entirely sure. Is your chrome and chrome driver up to date? You could also try running in headless mode (not sure if it will make a difference) with "chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")" but you'll have to validate that youre indeed getting redirected since you wont be able to see the window

Comment: When I copy your code (and the chrome is openned without extensions) the popup 'Please install metamask' appears =/

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps to use **Metamask extension** on your **automation test** on your **chrome browser** with **Selenium** on **Python**:

1- At the first step, you must install Metamask extension on your Chrome browser:

```
import urllib
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import *
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec

metamask_path = "Path of .crx file extension of metamask on your project"
if not os.path.exists(metamask_path):
    print('Setting up metamask extension please wait...')
    url = 'https://xord-testing.s3.amazonaws.com/selenium/10.0.2_0.crx'
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, metamask_path)
    print(f"Metamask Extension downloaded and added to Path: {metamask_path}")
chrome_options.add_extension(metamask_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
sleep(2)
print("Metamask Extension has been loaded!")
driver.maximize_window()
```

2- At the second step, because of Metamask extension installation a new tab has been opened that isn't necessary now, close it and open the target site url:

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1]) # jump to metamsk tab
driver.close() # close metamsk tab for now
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
driver.get('https://marketplace.plantvsundead.com/#/login')
```

3- At the third step, click on **Log in with MetaMask** button:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__layout"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/button').click()
time.sleep(2)
```

now find the Metamask extension tab that newly opened on your browser:

```
for handle in driver.window_handles:
    driver.switch_to.window(handle)
    if driver.title == "MetaMask":
        break # to stay in this chrome tab
```

4- At the forth step: you must import your wallet to Metamask extension.

> Note that: on **Metamask extension** on chrome browser the
> **.click()** function **doesn't work**. You can use **.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)** instead.

```
# wait for metamask extension page loading
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/button')))
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/button').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
# I have a wallet and I want to import my wallet
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/button')))
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/button').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
# I want/don't want MetaMask use my data to Help Improve MetaMask. 
# I select **No Thanks** button
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[5]/div[1]/footer/button[1]')))
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[5]/div[1]/footer/button[1]').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
# Import an account 
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/form/div[4]/div[1]/div/input')))
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/form/div[4]/div[1]/div/input').send_keys(["your Secret Recovery Phrase", Keys.TAB, Keys.TAB])
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/form/div[5]/div/input').send_keys(["your Metamask password", Keys.TAB])
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/form/div[6]/div/input').send_keys(
        ["your Metamask password", Keys.TAB])
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/form/div[7]/div').send_keys(
        [Keys.ENTER, Keys.TAB, Keys.TAB])
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/form/button').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/button')))
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/button').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/button[2]').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/footer/button[2]').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

5- by click on connect button in step 4, you will connect to the Metamask wallet on your extension!

Now, you can go back to your target site:

```
driver.close()
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```